# Big error about data type not supported in JAX-RPC specification using Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, apache-axis

This has never happened before. Never have I seen ANY of these warnings. There must be a small fix that I'm missing.

There is no way I can take out all instances of Class, Object, Map, etc. as it says I must. I've used these before in the same web service and had no problem. I added one method that is similar to the rest and I get this =S

Can anyone help?

```
The service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly.
  The field or property "headers" on the value type "org.apache.axis.AxisFault" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.util.ArrayList", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "cause" on the value type "java.rmi.RemoteException" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.lang.Throwable", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "noClasses" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "noObjects" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.lang.Object", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "propertyDescriptorMap" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.util.Map", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "type" on the value type "org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "actualType" on the value type "org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "javaType" on the value type "org.apache.axis.description.FieldDesc" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "headers" on the value type "org.apache.axis.AxisFault" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.util.ArrayList", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The field or property "cause" on the value type "java.rmi.RemoteException" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" has a data type, "java.lang.Throwable", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may result.
  The value type "org.w3c.dom.Element" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.apache.axis.utils.BeanPropertyDescriptor" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The value type "org.apache.axis.description.FieldDesc" used via the service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value type during deserialization.
  The service class "aaa.bbb.Indy.WebService.Functions" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 10.1 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a service class to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the service class to handle an incoming request message.
```

Comment: Could you post your method signature? I think you are using some class that is not serializable.

Comment: thanks for the reply =) i know that the actual code is not the problem, because i sent the class to my coworker and it was built and deployed in his environment without any problem. this is an eclipse issue =(

Comment: Can you try compiling the code without eclipse (using `javac`) ? If that works, you just need to tweak the eclipse warning / compile-errors configurations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be because you are trying to pass a List as parameter and the JAX-RPC spec does not specify a clear mapping between the java.util.List object and XML.The good news is you have other options. For your example, you could declare the type of 'actors' in the parameter itself. For example, use a String[] or Actors[] (where Actors is a complex type).

Comment: hi JAiro, i know that the code does not need to be changed, because it builds on my coworkers environment.

Comment: But what to do if we want to return Util.List into the Webservice

Answer (score 2):

Check that when creating the Web Service that the Web Service runtime Configuration is correct.

You might be trying to use Apache Axis rather than Apache CXF 2.x. On the first Web Services dialog click on Web service runtime and select Apache CXF 2.x.