# The service class does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap

I am new to Java Webservices, currently I am trying to create a simple SOAP based web-services but getting issue in creating it.

Here is my webservice class:

```
@WebService
public class Teams {
    private TeamsUtility utils;

    public Teams() { 
       utils = new TeamsUtility(); 
       utils.make_test_teams();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public Team getTeam(String name) { return utils.getTeam(name); }

    @WebMethod
    public List<Team> getTeams() { return utils.getTeams(); }

    @WebMethod
    public String getDummyTeams() { return "Hi"; }
}
```

As you can see I have 3 methods here. Now if I just keep `getDummyTeams` and ask eclipse to create a WebService, then I have no issues. But when I tried to add remaining 2 methods `public Team getTeam(String name)` & `public List<Team> getTeams()` then while creating webservice I am getting error as :

> The service class "helloservice.endpoint.Teams" does not comply to one
>   or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not
>   deploy or function correctly.   The field or property "players" on the
>   value type "helloservice.endpoint.Team" used via the service class
>   "helloservice.endpoint.Teams" has a data type, "java.util.List", that
>   is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of the
>   type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or
>   complete failure of the Web service may result.

Here is my `Team` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Team implements Serializable{
    private List<Player> players;
    private String name;

    public Team() {
    }

    public Team(String name, List<Player> players) {
        setName(name);
        setPlayers(players);
    }
// Setter & Getter methods
}
```

Can you please help me how do I fix this issue? I want to use `java.util.List`. Is there any settings I have to change in eclipse to use collections while creating SOAP based web-services?

Comment: Just curious. Why are you using JAX-RPC and not the JAX-WS ? JAX-RPC is deprecated really. Even if your webservice has an rpc-encoded wsdl style (which is the only reason I can imagine, since JAX-WS doesn't support it), then still in my personal experience it's often easier to just use a JAXB type of mechanism with raw http communication. Or are there legacy reasons perhaps ? Just curious really.

Comment: @bvdb, I am new to web-services and learning it by practicing some examples, I thought I am using JAX-WS based on the annotations I have in my post linked to my question. I am using eclipse for developing, can you please guide me the right path, just now I realized that JAX-RPC is different than JAX-WS and my service is deployed as JAX-RPC. Can you please give some links where I can learn it properly.

Comment: mkyong has a good series of tutorials: http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-ws-tutorials/

Comment: @bvdb, Thanks a lot, I will go through them.

Comment: @user3181365: I merged your 2 questions, since they were so similar to one another.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a direct response to the question. But nevertheless I would like to point out that you may consider not to use JAX-RPC at all.

**First of all, JAX-RPC is an old API, which has been replaced with JAX-WS.**

> [Reasons you may want to stay with JAX-RPC 1.1](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc/): ... If you want to send SOAP encoded messages or create RPC/encoded style WSDL.

And that leads us to the question *"what is an **RPC-encoded** WSDL style?"*

The WSDL file contains the definition of the methods of your webservice. And there are 4 ways/styles to define these methods:

- RPC/encoded
- RPC/literal
- Document/encoded
- Document/literal

[Each style has advantages and disadvantages.](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/) The most important one is the following remark:

> **Although it is legal WSDL, RPC/encoded is not WS-I compliant.**

WS-I stands for "webservice interoperability". So, as the quote clarifies, even though JAX-RPC supports RPC/encoded WSDL files, that doesn't mean it's compatible with other RPC/encoded technologies (e.g. webservices written in PHP). JAX-RPC webservices between Java and PHP may seem to work at first, but will sometimes break in specific cases. **So the lesson is: avoid RPC/encoded WSDL files.** And that's exactly why JAX-WS doesn't support them.

Unfortunately, sometimes you don't have a choice (e.g. another company provides the webservice) If it's a RPC/encoded WSDL file, then you won't be able to use JAX-WS. **If the hosted webservice is also written in Java, then you could risk using JAX-RPC. If it's written in some other language, then I wouldn't take the risk**. You're better of writing a custom handler when that happens. *(You can still safely use JAXB (Java Xml Binding) to perform the (un)marshalling (conversion from/to xml) using annotations, just like with JAX-WS webservices.)*

But how do you know if it's an RPC/encoded WSDL file? You just open it in a text editor, and look for the binding tag. The following example is an RPC/literal style WSDL file. So you can use JAX-WS with this webservice.

```
<binding name="MyService" type="tns:MyService">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
  <operation name="method">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <input>
      <soap:body use="literal" .../>
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use="literal" .../>
    </output>
  </operation>
</binding>
```

When you define your own webservice, you can choose the WSDL style by annotating your class with `@SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC, use=Use.LITERAL)`.

**A source of confusion:** both JAX-RPC and JAX-WS use SOAP. There's also a thing called `XML-RPC` which is an old standard (before SOAP). **But JAX-RPC does not use `XML-RPC`.** On the other hand, SOAP is sometimes called "XML **based** RPC".

Answer (score 0):

I think JAX RPC 1.1 doesn't support List as data type for service bean classes. Use Array instead. you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4808018/big-error-about-data-type-not-supported-in-jax-rpc-specification-using-eclipse) answer for similar issue

Comment: I want to use List in my program, I guess there should be some setting which I am missing to fix this issue for creating webservice. Please suggest how to fix the issue even when I use List.

Comment: From the error message, It seems you are using JAX RPC 1.1. You might want to check [this](http://www.straub.as/java/ws/jsr101/jax_rpc-1_1-mrel-spec.pdf) link which explains supported data types for this version. You can check from section 4.2

Comment: yes I agree, i am using eclipse to develop this, how to fix the issue without changing data types? because collections are better than ararys, and there should be some solution to this, may be not using JAX RPC but I want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason why the collection classes are not standardized for use in Java Web services is that they are loosely typed collections. In the absence of significant additional data from the user, it is not possible to map a Java collection to a well-defined Schema and clear rules to the runtime for serializing and deserializing elements of the collection.

Use Java arrays instead of collections to represent sequences of elements in WSDL. Java arrays are strongly typed and, as a result, map to and from strongly-typed Schema, yielding interoperable WSDL and SOAP traffic with clear rules for deserialization and serialization to and from Java. 
See [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21204381).

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RPC 1.1 spec provides something called pluggable serializers and deserializers to support collection classes.

Comment: Thanks for responding, can you please tell how to fix the issue, can you provide some link where the steps are given to fix this issue?

Comment: I hope below link will add some help. http://otndnld.oracle.co.jp/document/products/as10g/101300/B25221_03/web.1013/b25603/custserial.htm

Answer (score 0):

JAX-RPC 1.1 spec does not specify a clear mapping between the java.util.List object and XML.since you are returning java.util.List type.

change your method like

```
public Team[] getTeams() { return utils.getTeams(); }
```

And your `getTeams()` implementation should be match with this.