# How to use List for creating SOAP webservice in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap

This is an extension to my previous question posted - [The service class does not comply to one or more requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or function correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606020/the-service-class-does-not-comply-to-one-or-more-requirements-of-the-jax-rpc-1-1)

I was not able to use `java.util.List` while creating simple SOAP based web-services in eclipse using Java.

Is there any settings I have to change in eclipse to use collections while creating SOAP based web-services?